TV show that was on Netflix with a Viking boy who is in the modern world and a friend who is a ginger school kid
The show's name was very obscure and the Viking was not from this world. The boy and the Viking love pancakes.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was it live-action or animated?

My first thought was Ragnarok but that's not that obscure, no ginger boy, and no pancakes.

Is this Fangbone! (2014–2017)...?
From Wikipedia:

Fangbone! is a Canadian animated children's television series developed by Simon Racioppa & Richard Elliott and it was produced by Radical Sheep Productions and Pipeline Studios in association with DHX Media. It is based on the books by Michael Rex.
[...]
It has been on the Netflix streaming service from April 21, 2017 to 2021.

Fangbone is a young member of the barbarian Lizard Clan who reside on the planet Skullbania. The wizard of his clan, Twinkle-Stick, sent him through a portal to Earth with the big toe of the evil wizard, Drool, to keep it from him, since his power is greatly reduced without it.
After arriving on Earth, Fangbone meets and befriends a ginger-haired school boy named Bill Goodwin, whom he comes to regard as his 'battle brother.' He also starts attending school with Bill and coming over to his house to eat stacks of waffles prepared by Bill's mother. He makes a home for himself in an underground cave accessed through a small island in a river running through town.



Each episode typically involves the pair having to fight off a different monster/creature of the week that Drool sends to Earth to retrieve his toe. He can't retrieve the toe himself, since he draws his power from Skullbania and is entirely powerless on Earth without the toe.
Fangbone and Bill are shown scarfing down waffles at around the 0:34 mark in the video below. They also love to eat hot dogs at the local diner.



